# What is this leaf vegetable with red veins and leaf tips?

Tags: identification, vegetables

I live in Bristol, UK, and I have received this locally grown leaf vegetable, but I don't know what it is.

[image: Unknown vegetable]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The red spine and red tint on the fringe of the leaves lead me to either [Russian Red/Ragged  Kale](http://www.gardenbetty.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/2011-02-21-02.jpg) or [Winter Red Kale](http://www.wildgardenseed.com/images/WinterRedKale.jpg). From what I can tell, it's almost certainly a hybridized kale.

Comment: My sister has some that got planted way too late last season and has over-wintered despite the 12°F cold snaps. Russian Red Kale is the variety and just waiting for the first warmth to start growing again.

Comment: Agreed it has red russian roots (no pun intended): here is a good pictorial of kale: http://www.johnnyseeds.com/c-30-kale.aspx?source=W_veg_ddcat